# Angular Difference between ngIf and ng-if

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

I am wondering what the difference between ngIf and ng-if is. In some sources I have seen ngIf used and in some sources ng-if used. I know ngIf vs *ngIf. That is not my question so do not get confused with that question. The dash is what I do not understand.

Comment: As far as I know `ng-if` is used in AngularJs and `*ngIf` in Angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Angular documentation, [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) is an Angular (v +2) directive
, however, [ng-if](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-if.asp) is an AngularJS (v 1.x) directive.

as also mentioned by @rcoro in comments.

Comment: No, you can use either `ngIf` or `*ngIf` in 2+ versions.